# Meteor: use dropdown menu to get data from mongodb and show results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm new from Meteor, and I need to realize a little dropdown menu and a search with the selected data in the dropdown menu.

I have `devices.html` :

```
<div class="ha_panel-selections">
    <form id="plane-form">
        <select id="plane-select">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
            {{#each plane}}
                <option id="plane_selected" value="{{this}}">{{this.planeid}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

the data comes from the database: `devices.js` is:

```
    Template.devices.helpers({
        plane: function() {
            return plane.find({});
        }
    });
```

Now what I want to do is take the selected value in the dropdown menu (the `plane.planeid` value), search in the db for that value, and print the data associated: 
so for example, if I select "plane1" I can see planeid, flighttime, pilotname, ecc; if I change from "plane1" to "plane2" the data will change accordingly.

How can I pass the `plane_selected` value from html to devices.js? and back, once i will find the data in the db, how can I print the results passing the data form `devices.js` to `devices.html` ?

I think it should be (in `devices.js`) something like

```
Template.devices.events({
    "change #plane-form": function (event, template) {
        //console.log("event: " + util.inspect(event) );
        //console.log("template: " + util.inspect(template) );
        var selected = Session.get("plane_selected");
        console.log("selected: " + selected);
    }
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```"change #plane-select"``` instead of ```"change #plane-form"```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that you're able to select the `planeid`, you're pub/sub seems to be working. All you need is another helper that give you back the rest of the plane's data.

**devices.js**

```
Template.devices.events({
    "change #plane-select": function (event, template) {

        var selected = event.target.value;
        console.log("selected: " + selected);
        Session.set("selectedPlane", selected);
    }
});


Template.devices.helpers({
    plane: function() {
        return plane.find({});
    },

    planeData: function() {
        return planes.findOne({
            planeId: Session.get("selectedPlane")
        });
    }
});
```

**devices.html**

```
<p>
planeID: {{planeData.planeid}}
planeName: {{planeData.planeName}}
...
...
</p>
```

**Note**: It's up to you to use `Session` or `reactive var`s `Session` variables are lost on page refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this way it works! I also learned that I can't just log Session.set: i tried `var test = Session.set(...)` and `console.log(test)` but this does not work. And this is logically correct in fact.

Instead, i tred `var test = Session.get(...)` and this logs correctly.

Comment: ```Session.set("var", true)``` ==> means that you've assigned true to a session variable called ```var```. If you want to retrieve the value of ```var```, then you need to do ```Session.get("var")```. You can't set ```var test = Session.set(...)```. It should be``` var test = Session.get(...)```